# What all techniques are used to display blood in films/television shows?

Tags: film-techniques, realism

In recent times, in movies and television shows when someone is stabbed or shot or injured in any other way the blood coming out of their body seems very real in terms of its the color, viscosity, and the speed at which comes out of the body.

1. What all techniques, mechanisms/equipments, and materials/chemicals are used for this purpose?
2. Has there been a time where real blood is used to give it a real-life look/effect? (Sounds creepy I know)

Comment: I did the zombie in a splatter movie about 10 years ago. They had used glycose syrup for the blood.